# Proper way to round a second-precision count-down display

Tags: time, language-agnostic, rounding, standards, date-formatting

I need to display a time span to the user, in `m:ss` format, that indicates how far in the future an event happpens (e.g. download finished).

Now assume, the event is 1,3s in the future. Should I display `0:01` or `0:02`?

- The former (rounding down) seems to be more natural in that it is consistent with a hypothetical, more precise `0:01.500` display.
- The latter avoids the awkward situation that the display will show `0:00` for one second, until the event actually occurs.

Is there a standard on this matter that offers guidance?

Comment: Do you really care what a person would notice in a timespan of 1 seconds compared to waiting say 10 minutes?

Comment: Yes, we just had a lengthy discussion about this. Consider a display in a racing game, where the player wants to start the engine precisely when the round starts: He will be surprised if – to his understanding – the count down is off by one second.

Comment: I would display millisecond resolution then ie `01:01.023`

Comment: @lappie: Yes, that is an obvious way out – if the UI allows it. But what if there are UI constraints that prevent that?

Comment: Even 10th's of a second would be OK, IMO. Else I would probably use `ceiling` for 'rounding'

Answer (score 0):

if you count **down**, you should display ceiling.

```
1,7 -> 2
1,2 -> 2
1,0 -> 1
0,1 -> 1
0,0 -> 0
```

this way you will get 'instant end' (no 0:00 for one second) and proper perceived remaining time: when user/player see 0:01, he knows he has one second left.

Comment: “when user/player see 0:01, he knows he has one second left.” that’s wrong, isn’t it? Or do you mean ”when user sees the clock switch to 0:01,...”?

Comment: Also, is this based on personal opinion or based on some standard or other authoritative source?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner yes, i meant when user sees the switch. i don't think there is something like 'authoritative source' for this :) it's like all the counters i've ever seen work. games, clock alarms etc.